# How to show AlertDialog after ArrayList is true or completed in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist, dialog

I have list from API that show data class as follow:

```
data class Ibadah(
val ibadahText: String,
val id: Int,
val isComplete: Boolean,
val journalId: Int,
val userId: String
)
```

and this class:

```
@Singleton
class IbadahRVAdapter @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<IbadahRVAdapter.IbadahViewHolder>() {
lateinit var ibadahslist: List<Ibadah>
@Named("journal_url")
@Inject
lateinit var journalInterface: JournalInterface
lateinit var ibadahs_isCompleted: ArrayList<Boolean>
lateinit var ibadahList: ArrayList<Ibadah>
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
var jId = 0

inner class IbadahViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IbadahViewHolder {
    val view =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.ibadah_rv_item, parent, false)
    return IbadahViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return ibadahslist.size
}

fun setQuranSurahList(quransurahlist: List<Ibadah>) {
    this.ibadahslist = quransurahlist;
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IbadahViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ibadahs_isCompleted = ArrayList()
    holder.itemView.apply {
        ibadah_item_text.setText(ibadahslist[position].ibadahText)
        ibadah_item_chechbox.setChecked(ibadahslist[position].isComplete)
        ibadah_item_chechbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { checkBox, isChecked ->
            patchIbadah(position)
            if (!ibadahs_isCompleted.contains(false)) {

                AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setView(R.layout.finish_ibadh)


                    .show()


            } else {
                

            }
        }

    }
}
fun patchIbadah(position: Int) {
    getToken()
    journalInterface.patchIbadah(ibadahslist[position].id, token)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                response: Response<ResponseBody>
            ) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    getIbadahsList()
                    Log.e(this.toString(), "code: " + response.code())

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(this.toString(), "error: " + t.message)
            }

        })

}

fun setupRV() {

    this.setQuranSurahList(ibadahList)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    recyclerView.adapter = this


}

fun getIbadahsList() {


    ibadahList = ArrayList()

    journalInterface.getIbadahs(jId, token).enqueue(object : Callback<List<Ibadah>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<Ibadah>>,
            response: Response<List<Ibadah>>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                response.body()?.forEach {
                    ibadahList.add(
                        Ibadah(
                            it.ibadahText, it.id, it.isComplete, it.journalId, it.userId
                        )
                    )
                    ibadahs_isCompleted.add(it.isComplete)
                }
                setupRV()


            } else {
                

            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Ibadah>>, t: Throwable) {
            
        }

    })

}


}
```

to show list like this:

[image]

My current code show the `AlertDialog`, if I check or uncheck any item.

`AlertDialog` is placed in `onBindViewHolder`.

**I want the `AlertDialog` to appear only if all items are checked and if any item of the list not checked, do not appear.**

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I must say that your code structure is very odd. Having the RecyclerView inside your Adapter, as well as the Adapter in charge of showing the AlertDialog is not considered a common practice. An Adapter should take care of creating the items that are added to the RecyclerView, that's it. Having said that, this call: patchIbadah(position) is a-synchronic and it means that the code doesn't wait for it to complete before it reaches this check: !ibadahs_isCompleted.contains(false).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be showing AlertDialog inside the adapter. use listener to update your changes in Fragment/Activity.

**Solution for your question:** Assign new/another list in Fragment/Activity whatever the changes are made just pass through the listener and add those changes to the new list, then validate that the original list size equals to new list size. If the condition is true then show AlertDialog.